# show that there is one point whose co-ordinates do not alter due to a rigid motion

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have chosen a point  $A(x,y)$.
And let the origin be shifted to $(a,b)$
Now $A(x+a,y+b)$
If the rotation is  $\theta$,

$$x= X\cos\theta -  Y\sin\theta$$
$$y= X\sin\theta + Y\cos\theta$$

Now I wonder what to do.

Comment: This is unclear. Translations are rigid motions that leave no point fixed. What is fixed when you rotate about the origin as in your question?

Comment: But the question is said like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to show that exist $x$ **fixed point** such that

$$x=Rx+x_0 \implies(I-R)x=x_0$$

and thus that

- for $x_0=0 \implies x=0$ (no translation)

or

- for $x_0\neq 0 \quad (I-R)$ is invertible and $x=(I-R)^{-1}x_0$

Comment: But from this how can we say that #x is fixed point?

Comment: @Kaushik in general $Rx+x_0\neq x$ here we have set $x=Rx+x_0$ that is the condition to have x as fixed point